# How to scrape data based on class tag and attribute name in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping, dart-html

I tried to find the alternative way to scrape data in this html. The value I tried to get is the **'e4s1' value**.

```
<section class="row btn-row">
        <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="e4s1"/>
```

Basically I have found a way to get this value using the following code. But this is dependent on the tag location in the html code. Which in this case at 'input'[2].

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;

.....
Future getLoginAuth() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: header);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      dom.Document document = parse(response.body);
      final elements =
          document.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].attributes['value'];
      print(elements);
    }
......
```

**So, is there a way to find the value 'e4s1' using tag and also the name attribute?** For example, using tag:input and attribute: name='execution'. I am trying to find a way to do this in Dart like using BeautifulSoup package in python as shown in the code below:

```
soup.find('input', attrs={'name':'execution'})['value']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the HTML using the [xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) package. Something like this:

```
final html = 
'''<section class="row btn-row">
        <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="e4s1"/>
</section>''';

final document = XmlDocument.parse(html);
final inputs = document.findAllElements('input');

inputs.forEach((node) => print(node.attributes));
```

`attributes` is a list of all the attributes in the current node.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @user2233706 that leads me to use forEach(). So, this is how I do it using [HTML](https://pub.dev/packages/html) package:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;


Future getLoginAuth() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: header);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      dom.Document document = parse(response.body);
      List data = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

      data.forEach(
        (element) {
          if (element.attributes.containsValue('execution') == true) {
            print(element.attributes['value']);
          }
        },
      );   
      }
```